# Is economics worthy of a Stack Exchange site?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange

There're Stack Exchange sites for physics, cooking, finance, etc. Where is **economics**? We need a Stack Exchange site for the community to ask and answer day-to-day economy phenomenon - why a certain thing happens and what causes it.

Q&A on economics would at least, IMHO, be more objective than cooking and physics.

Comment: There is absolutely no way that economics is more objective than physics. None. Sorry.

Comment: Like LegalOverflow, sounds like a good way to get your ass sued.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is the Economics proposal already

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics

Answer (score 4):

There is now a new Economics.SE beta which you can access at https://economics.stackexchange.com/.